# USB MULTIBOOT with GRUB and options

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, usb

Is it possible to make an USB installer with the option of more than one release?

I have a 16GB USB stick and I would like to have the choice to install either AMD64 or i386 or perhaps the option of Ubuntu 12.04 or Lubuntu 12.04.

Can the stick be partitioned with a grub loader to give a choice of installers. Ideally Ubuntu 12.04, Lubuntu, 12.04 and debian6.0.7 with the boot recovery disk and a few windows applications as a toolkit.

In theory it should be quite straight forward, get the stick to boot into grub and the different installers in the various partitions.

I have attempted partitioning the stick and tried installing grub to it also but cant get it to boot. Probably impossible but then nothing is truly impossible... or is it?
No panic, just for giggles and to kill time and the occasional OS.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible. There is a great guide [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/).